# Ajax no hereda estilos, eventos al DOM

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Amigos estoy jugando con ajax un poco, pero veo que cuando cargo elementos al DOM por AJAX se pierden los estilos. por ejemplo este scrollbar que encontré por internet.
Cuando tiene carga normal, se agrega a a la clase "scrollbar-container" esto: "ps ps--active-y" quedando así class="scrollbar-container ps ps--active-y" y tambien vi que se añade estos codigos dentro del div que tiene la clase "scrollbar-container"

```
<div class="ps__rail-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div class="ps__thumb-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
<div class="ps__rail-y" style="top: 0px; height: 200px; right: 0px;"><div class="ps__thumb-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 77px;"></div></div>
```

Cómo se puede solucionar el estilo del scrollbar para cuando sea llamado por AJAX no se pierda el estilo chulisimo que tiene?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CARGA NORMAL DE LA PÁGINA SIN AJAX
(el siguiente código es sacado al inspeccionar la página, es decir que se añade al DOM)

```
<div class="scrollbar-container ps ps--active-y">
  <h4>Hola mundo</h4>                  
  <div class="ps__rail-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="ps__thumb-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ps__rail-y" style="top: 0px; height: 200px; right: 0px;">
    <div class="ps__thumb-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 81px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CARGA CON AJAX

```
<div class="scrollbar-container">
  <h4>Hola mundo</H4>
</div>
```

Comment: con click derecho puedes darle inpeccionar en chrome o el firefox y puedes ver como lo esta cargado desde ajax

Comment: el código de la seccion "CARGA NORMAL DE LA PÁGINA SIN AJAX" se añade automáticamente al cargar la página, eso lo saque con inspeccionar elemento.

Comment: ¿Y la llamada `Ajax`? No podemos adivinar lo que estás haciendo, debes mostrar el código de tu llamada para poder entender el problema. Por favor leer [mcve]. Saludos